# Waf fails to configure C compiler on github actions

Tags: c, github-actions, waf

When I run `./waf configure -v` locally, I get

```
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : 13:52:02 runner ['/usr/bin/gcc', '-dM', '-E', '-']
/usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : 13:52:02 runner ['clang', '-dM', '-E', '-']
not found 
Checking for 'clang' (C compiler)        : 13:52:02 runner ['clang', '-dM', '-E', '-']
clang 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : 13:52:02 runner ['/usr/bin/gcc', '-dM', '-E', '-']
/usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : 13:52:02 runner ['clang', '-dM', '-E', '-']
not found 
Checking for 'clang' (C compiler)        : 13:52:02 runner ['clang', '-dM', '-E', '-']
clang 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : 13:52:02 runner ['x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc', '-dM', '-E', '-']
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
```

However, when I run it on github actions, I NEED it to specifically use `clang-15` and `gcc-13` which are installed manually.  It actually does discover `clang-15` on its own if I just run `./waf configure -v`, but it still gives up for absolutely no reason.

If I run it with `CC=clang-15 ./waf configure -v` it still fails with the same error.

The error for just `./waf configure -v` is

```
 Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : 19:30:07 runner ['/usr/bin/gcc', '-dM', '-E', '-']
/usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : 19:30:08 runner ['clang', '-dM', '-E', '-']
not found 
Checking for 'clang' (C compiler)        : 19:30:10 runner ['clang', '-dM', '-E', '-']
clang 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : 19:30:10 runner ['/usr/bin/gcc', '-dM', '-E', '-']
/usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : 19:30:10 runner ['clang', '-dM', '-E', '-']
not found 
Checking for 'clang' (C compiler)        : 19:30:10 runner ['clang', '-dM', '-E', '-']
clang 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : not found 
Checking for 'clang' (C compiler)        : not found 
Checking for 'icc' (C compiler)          : not found 
could not configure a C compiler!
```

The astute reader will notice that (a) these outputs are different, and (b) on gha, Waf has very mysteriously decided that it will refuse to work even though it patently found `clang` and `/usr/bin/gcc` successfully.

What is going on here?  This doesn't make any sense at all.  It's incoherent.

Like, fair play it's finding different compilers on my system vs gha; they have different compilers installed so this makes sense.  But, truly, WHY is it attempting to find `icc` on gha but not my computer, and WHY is it giving up due to not finding a C compiler on gha but not my computer when, again, it finds a C compiler on both?

I certainly have no idea what could possibly be causing this failure, but it should be obvious already to anyone who does.  Nevertheless, here is the [gha workflow](https://github.com/hacatu/Number-Theory-Utils/blob/master/.github/workflows/cov_and_docs.yml) and here is the [wscript](https://github.com/hacatu/Number-Theory-Utils/blob/master/wscript) (beware it's chonky).

I've searched Waf's gitlab issues, stackoverflow, and google, but I didn't find much useful.  I did find that Waf will display the output of the compiler on an empty program if you look in its log files, since this was relevant in one gitlab issue where the user had a custom compiler that Waf didn't recognize, but I really have gcc and clang so this should not be the problem.  I also found that there's some way to make ubuntu use clang-15 and gcc-13 by default, I think this might actually help but I remember it (shock of shocks) not working on gha in the past.

EDIT: To be clear, I was thinking of `update-alternatives`, and when using `update-alternatives` to change `gcc-13` and `clang-15` to the deaults, there is no change to the Waf failure.  However, I did verify by adding `gcc --version` etc to the gha script that the default `gcc` correctly becomes `gcc-13` and the default clang becomes ... `clang-14` (wild).

Comment: Here is the configure.log from waf running on gha: https://gist.github.com/hacatu/876d1c1152705c7c676674613ce5c1dc

Comment: For now I have managed to resolve the failure by 1) checking if `GITHUB_RUN_ID` is defined in `os.environ` and if so 2) setting `ctx.env.CC='clang-15'` in variants that should be built with clang instead of `ctx.env.CC='clang'`, and similarly for `gcc`, cross-gcc, `ctx.env.LD`, and so on.  Basically it seems that Waf's c compiler search is deficient overriding CC can only help if you only need one compiler.  I might add flags like `--overide-clang`